# I am getting this issue "The folder does not contain Android SDK"

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, sdk

I have installed Android Studio but it didn't have SDK tools so I downloaded the platform tools separately. I have used the SDK location in the platform-tools but the issue keeps happening. Any idea how do I resolve it?

Comment: I have checked that ADB is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Within Android Studio, you can install the Android  SDK as follows:

```
Click Tools > SDK Manager.
In the SDK Platforms tab, select Android 12.
In the SDK Tools tab, select Android SDK Build-Tools 31.
Click OK to install the SDK.
```

Comment: Plus I checked in the android studio folder there is no SDK manager in it

Comment: then re install android studio it will automatically check for android sdk if there is any android sdk it will detect it otherwise it will download sdk again